# Nested NSDictionary & NSArray with AFNetworking not working properly

Tags: ios, json, node.js, nsurlrequest, afnetworking

```
NSDictionary *customerDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"blah@blah.com", @"email", @"1", @"facebook", nil];
NSArray *customerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:customerDictionary, nil];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:customerArray, @"customers", nil];
NSURLRequest *request = [sharedHTTPClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/api/upload" parameters:parameters];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {}
                                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {}];
[operation start];
```

On a Node.JS backend, printing out the body shows:

```
{ customers: [ '1', 'blah@blah.com' ] }
```

Expected print should be:

```
{ customers: [{ facebook:'1', email:'blah@blah.com' }] }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be you are printing wrong? Looks like it is problem on server, not iOS

Comment: You'd better offer the code on server side either.

Comment: Log the post body before sending the request to see if it is correct

Comment: The print out is is a simple console.log in Node.JS of the req.body. It's the raw print out. Anyways phix23's answer did it for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the AFNetworking wiki:

> **How do I send JSON parameters in my request?**
>
> If you're using AFHTTPClient, set the parameterEncoding property to
> AFJSONParameterEncoding. Any method on that HTTP client with a
> parameters argument will now encode the passed object into a JSON
> string and set the HTTP body and Content-Type header appropriately.
>
> Otherwise, you can do this manually by adding the header Content-Type:
> application/json, and setting the body of your request to a JSON
> string.

Comment: Geez, no matter how many times I've read the wiki, I somehow skipped this part. This did it for me! Thanks. (can't award bounty until 11 hours).